# Mass of a particle ( relativity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, mass, velocity, mass-energy

> A hypothetical atom has a rest mass of $15.000000136\,\mathrm{u}$. Overtime it undergoes a spontaneous breakdown into two masses of $7.000000229\,\mathrm{u}$ and $6.902727019\,\mathrm{u}$ respectively.  If, after the breakdown, the first particle of mass of $7.000000229\,\mathrm{u}$, receives all the excess energy of the breakdown, how fast will the particle be traveling.  Report your answer in $c$.

I dont want the direct answer, but would like the procedure.

Do I use the conservation of energy $E = E_{rest} + E_k$?

If so what masses do I use, because in my homework slides it says to take $m$, as the difference of the breakdowns. I am really confused as to what it means by after the breakdown the mass of the particle is $7.0000000029\,\mathrm{u}$, what masses do we use?

Comment: I just wanted to know what formula to use and what the subscripts meant. In some problems they use the mass difference of the atoms and in others they use the given mass, I just wanted to know which one to use that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's hard to imagine the first particle alone getting all the kinetic energy: the most obvious scenario is with the atom at rest, so the total momentum of all the fragments in the center of mass frame is nought.

However, supposing it were possible for the first particle to get all the kinetic energy, then the total energy of the first particle is $E_t=15.000\cdots - 6.902\cdots=8.1\cdots$. The rest mass of this particle is $7.000\cdots$. Now use $E^2 - p^2 \,c^2 = m_0^2\,c^4$, where you're going to put $m_0=7.\cdots$ and $E=8.1\cdots$. This gives you a value for $p$ (set $c=1$ for the units you need) and then convert to a speed by $p = m_0\,\gamma\,v$, *i.e.* $p=\frac{m_0\,v}{1-v^2}$.

Comment: thank you! I found this formula in the slides somehow it was sneaked under a bunchof stuff

Comment: Are you missing an m in the momentum conversion equation?

Comment: Hello again, could you explain more reasoning into why you subtracted the 6.9 from 15 to get E and made m = 7. In another problem I did to find energy the solution manual used the mass of one particle - the mass of another particle, and then used E= mo * c^2. Where mo = particle 1 - particle 2.